# wrapping cuda memory handling in a class leads to corrupt memory adresses

Tags: c++, cuda

To have more comfort handling memory on host and device, I created the following class.
In theory it should manage copying from host to device and vice versa.

```
struct CudaArray
{

int* memoryHost;
int* memoryDevice;

int size;

CudaArray(int datasize) // creates array on host and allocates memory on device with cudaMalloc
{
    size = datasize;
    memoryHost = new int[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        memoryHost[i] = 0;
    }

    cudaMalloc((void**)&memoryDevice, sizeof(int) * size);
}

~CudaArray() // frees memory on device and host
{
    delete[] memoryHost;
    cudaFree(memoryDevice);
}

void Upload() // upload data from host to device
{
    cudaMemcpy(memoryDevice, memoryHost, sizeof(int) * size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
}
void Download() // download data from device to host
{
    cudaMemcpy(memoryHost, memoryDevice, sizeof(int) * size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
}

void Insert(int* src); // copy from src to memoryHost
void Retrieve(int* dest); // copy from memoryHost to dest
};
```

Internally, everything is alright. But when I use an object of my CudaArray, there are problems with the pointers:

```
CudaArray cuda_ar(1000);
kernel <<<blocks, threads_per_block>>> (cuda_ar.memoryDevice, cuda_ar.size);
```

By using the debugger, I managed to read the pointer memoryDevice. Inside the struct (e.g. when stepping through Upload(), it is 0x01000000. But at the place where the kernel is executed, memoryDevice points to 0x00000400 (numbers are examples).

I know that memoryDevice is a pointer pointing to memory on the device.
Is there a way to explain this behavior and give a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run the following program

```
#include <cstdio>
struct CudaArray
{

  int* memoryHost;
  int* memoryDevice;

  int size;

  CudaArray(int datasize) // creates array on host and allocates memory on device with cudaMalloc
  {
    size = datasize;
    memoryHost = new int[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
      memoryHost[i] = 0;
    }

    cudaMalloc((void**)&memoryDevice, sizeof(int) * size);
}

~CudaArray() // frees memory on device and host
{
  delete[] memoryHost;
  cudaFree(memoryDevice);
}

void Upload() // upload data from host to device
{
  cudaMemcpy(memoryDevice, memoryHost, sizeof(int) * size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
}
void Download() // download data from device to host
{
  cudaMemcpy(memoryHost, memoryDevice, sizeof(int) * size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
}

};

__global__ void kernel(int *ptr, int n)
{
  printf("On Device : %p %d\n", ptr, n);
}

int main(void)
{
  CudaArray cuda_ar(1000);
  printf("On Host   : %p %d\n", cuda_ar.memoryDevice, cuda_ar.size);
  kernel<<<1, 1>>>(cuda_ar.memoryDevice, cuda_ar.size);
  return 0;
}
```

I get

```
On Host   : 0x200400000 1000
On Device : 0x200400000 1000
```

You should make sure your CUDA runtime calls like cudaMalloc, cudaMemcpy and kernel launches are all returning successfully. You can try this code after all your CUDA runtime calls to verify that :

```
if (cudaSuccess != cudaGetLastError())
  printf( "Error!\n" );
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for the hint with cudaGetLastError(). Due to some strange value inside the Visual Studio project, the cuda-file was compiled with sm_13, while I only have sm_11. Now the code from above works! Thank you!